# get value form json object

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have a code which gets `List` of objects using Hibernate from db. One of the fields of object has XML format. I get that field value using this code in `jsp` file:

```
for(PluginMonitor pm : list ) {
    // parsing xml to json
    JSONObject metricsFieldValue = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(pm.getMetrics());
    Object metricMetric = metricsFieldValue.get("metric");      
}
```

output of `metricsFieldValue` is

```
{
    "metric": [
        {
            "defaultThreshold": "0",
            "preselected": "true",
            "uom": "B/sec",
            "name": "BytesReceivedPersec",
            "type": "integer",
            "displayName": "Input Traffic"
        },
        {
            "defaultThreshold": "0",
            "preselected": "true",
            "uom": "B/sec",
            "name": "BytesSentPersec",
            "type": "integer",
            "displayName": "Output Traffic"
        }
    ]
}
```

so output  of `metricMetric` is an Array, But I need only `displayName` and `name` of each object in that array. Any ideas how to get these values.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Strings saperately like;

```
String displayName = jo.getJSONArray("metric").getJSONObject(i).getString("displayName");
String name =  jo.getJSONArray("metric").getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` has a constructor that can pick specific fields from another `JSONObject`

```
public JSONObject(JSONObject jo, java.lang.String[] names)
```

> Construct a JSONObject from a subset of another JSONObject.
>   An array of strings is used to identify the keys that should be copied.
>   Missing keys are ignored.

In your case you would use it like this :

```
String[] fields = new String[] {"displayName", "name"};
JSONObject onlyNames = new JSONObject(metricsFieldValue, fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray metric = new JSONArray();
metric = metricsFieldValue.getJSONArray("metric");
for(int i=0; i< metric.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = metric.getJSONObject(i);
    String displayName = jsonObject.get("displayName");
    String name = jsonObject.get("name");
}
```

If you're using(importing) `org.json.simple.JSONArray`, you have to use `JSONArray.size()` to get the data you want. But use `JSONArray.length()` if you're using `org.json.JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

this is how it worked

```
List<PluginMonitor> list = new ArrayList<PluginMonitor>() ;
list = instance.getPluginMonitorList();
JSONObject metricsFieldValue = null;
JSONObject jo = null;
int listSize = list.size(); 
int ln = 0;
JSONObject json = null; 
JSONArray ja = null;
JSONObject jsonObj = null;  

for(PluginMonitor pm: list){
    if(pm == null) {continue;}
    try{
        json = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(pm.getMetrics());          
        ja = json.getJSONArray("metric");
        ln = ja.length();
        for(int k = 0; k < ln; k++ ){
            jsonObj = ja.getJSONObject(k);
            out.print( "<H1> Name: " +jsonObj.get("name") + "</h1>");
            out.print( "<H2 style='color: gray'> Display Name: " +jsonObj.get("displayName") + "</h2>"); 
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```